# Get raw html content from angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to have a directive that would show code snippet. It would looks like:

```
<code-snippet>
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div data-attr>Some html code here</div>
</code-snippet>
```

To prevent the `{{}}` being evaluated, I created a directive that would cache the html result at compile phase and return the link function to render this html:

```
app.directive("codeSnippet", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(tEl){
      var code = tEl.html();
      return function(scope, el){
        el.html("<pre><code>"+_.escape(code)+"</code></pre>");
      };
    }
  };
});
```

The result is render as:

```
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div data-attr="">Some html code here</div>
```

The original `data-attr` code is rendered as `data-attr=""`, which I believe is the result of `innerHTML` by the browser. So is there a way to get the raw inner html without browser's processing?

Comment: I think you should start your investigation how to obtain un-parsed html content using javascript.   My guess is that browser does not support such an operation.

Comment: I also think it is not supported.

Comment: You can apply dom parse on "element" object passed in directive.

Comment: @DilipKumar can you be more specific on that?

Comment: @jackysee you can use Jquery to parse "element" object. Please note; element object is nothing but representation of HTML structure. I will try to create sample jsfiddle and will share.